# Consume SNS Message from Python application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to read the message from the SNS topic from the python application.

Is there a way that we can consume the message from **SNS directly**?

Note:

- I am aware of the way SNS to SQS and consume the message from there.
  I want to consume the same message from the N number of instances So
  I am planning to consume from SNS directly instead of creating the N
  The number of SQS queues (N can increase or decrease dynamically).
- I will not be able to use Lambda or any other functions directly.

Comment: This sounds like something that is better solved with Kafka than SNS

Comment: This is just the simple implementation that occurs every 3 months once so don't want to complicate things with Kafka and trying to keep it simple.

Between if I consume the message in Kafka from consumer-A will that be available for consumer-B?

Comment: Yes each consumer group in kafka has their own offset (till which message it has consumed). You can also try the HTTP callback in SNS with web services to do the consuming.

Comment: AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

Comment: This allows one subscriber(via HTTPS), right?

Comment: You can subscribe multiple endpoints to the topic just like you would with SQS queues. Hence the term "fanout" used in the doc

Comment: So need to create multiple HTTPS endpoints?

Comment: Yes. One for each instance that needs to consume the notifications.

Comment: unable to use the private IP for consuming the SNS, is there something I am missing?